# Java Regex Not Matching When it Should

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to pull out a specific HTML a tag from some HTML that contains a specific date.

The HTML supplied to this in the unit test is:

Here is the Unit Test in question:

```
public void testParseBasePage(){
    defenseGovContractsParser a = new defenseGovContractsParser("060613");
    String expected = "http://www.defense.gov/contracts/contract.aspx?contractid=5059";
    String result = a.parseBasePage("<td><a id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Body_ContractSummary_dgPRItems_ctl02_lnkPressItem\" title=\"Click for Contracts for June 06, 2013\" class=\"Link12\" href=\"http://www.defense.gov/contracts/contract.aspx?contractid=5059\">Contracts for June 06, 2013</a><span id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Body_ContractSummary_dgPRItems_ctl02_lblSubTitle\" class=\"MoreNews3a\"></span></td>");
    assertEquals(expected,result);
}
```

Here's the code in question:

```
public String parseBasePage(String HTML) {
    String contractUrl;
    String yr = date.substring(4, 6);
    String day = date.substring(2, 4);
    String month = getMonthForInt(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2)));
    Pattern getLink = Pattern.compile("<a.*?" + month + ".*?" + day + ".*?20" + yr + ".*?>");
    Matcher match = getLink.matcher(HTML);
    String link = match.group();
    contractUrl = link.substring(link.indexOf("href") + 6);
    contractUrl = contractUrl.replaceFirst("\">", "");
    return contractUrl;
}

private String getMonthForInt(int m) {
    String month = "invalid";
    m = m - 1;
    DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
    String[] months = dfs.getMonths();
    if (m >= 0 && m <= 11) {
        month = months[m];
    }
    return month;
}
```

The resulting regex is:

```
<a.*?June.*?06.*?2013.*?>
```

which, when I use any online regex tester, matches as expected

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://jsoup.org/) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?answertab=oldest#tab-top)?

Comment: Getting to read that monologue was worth this question without an introduction to jsoup.  I'll use jsoup and not consume all living tissue in the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would *really* recommend a decent HTML parser such as [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) or [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) (perhaps confusingly named in this scenario), rather than use regepxs for this purpose.

For all but the simplest cases regexps will not work on HTML, and a decent HTML parser is going to be a much more reliable solution.

Comment: Just for anybody who sees this.  The actual mistake in this code that caused it not to work is that I never invoked match.find() before calling match.group().